# Botones con funciones

Tags: javascript, html, array, programación-funcional, onclick

Estaba intentando hacer un botón que al darle click, abra una ventana y pida la información de los jugadores (cuantos jugadores, nombre, apellido y su número de camiseta), tengo que hacerlo con arreglos y constructores de objetos.
Agradezco su tiempo :D

````
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="regisJugadores()">Registrar Jugadores</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var nombre = "";
    var apellido = "";
    var camiseta = "";
    var registro = 0;
        function regisJugadores(){
        for(let i = 5; i<=registro; i++){
            var nombre = (prompt("Ingresa el nombre del jugador"));
            var apellido = (prompt("Ingresa el apellido del jugador"));
            var camiseta = (prompt("Ingresa el número de camiseta del jugador"));

        
    }
        }
            
    
</script>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: ¿Estás utilizando algún framework como Bootstrap? Podrías incluir un formulario en una venta modal, posteriormente hacer un ajax para guardar los datos.

Answer (score 0):

No puedo realizarte el ejercicio completo, pero si puedo orientarte.

Para un constructor podrías realizarlo desde un script aparte e invocarlo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    class Jugador {
        constructor(nombre, apellido, camiseta) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.apellido = apellido;
            this.camiseta = camiseta;
        }
    }  
</script>
```

Para invocarlo solo tendrías que construirlo por cada jugador:

```
var Jugador = new Jugador("nombre","apellido",1);
```

e incluirlo en un array:

```
var array = [];
array.push(Jugador);
```

Luego, aprovechando el código que habías realizado he partido de ahí y he generado un ejemplo sin la clase para orientarte sobre como debería ser la estructura funcional:

```js
function regisJugadores(){
    /*nada mas empezar la función le pedimos el número para iterar y declaramos las
    array, con una clase solo necesitarias un array de tu objeto*/
    let numJugadores = prompt("Ingresa el número de jugadores");
    let nombres = [];
    let apellidos = [];
    let camisetas = [];
    /*iteramos los numeros de jugadores registrados y los introducimos en las arrays*/
    for(let i = 0; i < numJugadores; i++){
        let nombre = prompt("Ingresa el nombre del jugador");
      let apellido = prompt("Ingresa el apellido del jugador");
      let camiseta = prompt("Ingresa el número de camiseta del jugador");
      nombres.push(nombre);
      apellidos.push(apellido);
      camisetas.push(camiseta);
    }
    /*Mostramos un alert por jugador, esto con la clase seria algo como jugadores[item].Propiedad*/
    for(let item = 0; item < numJugadores; item++){
        alert("El jugador con la camiseta: " + camisetas[item] + " Se llama: " + nombres[item] + " " + apellidos[item]);
    }
  }
```

```html
 <button onclick="regisJugadores()">Registrar Jugadores</button>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo agradezco demasiado